# listen to change in state of location when user turns it on and off

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I saw many answers but none is working. The last one i have uses broadcasts but it is not working. Basically, if location is disabled, I ask the user to enable location first. The device settings does open and user enables location but if user presses the back button, the result is always RESULT_CANCELLED.

So I thought I would listen to changes as the user toggles state as shown in the [video](https://%20%20https://streamable.com/rkdak2) and as soon as it is enabled, I continue.

The user experience is terrible currently because the only way is to restart the app.

manifest

```
    <receiver android:name=".LocationBroadCast"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

LocationBroadCast

```
class LocationBroadCast(private val onProviderStatusChanged: (Boolean) -> Unit): BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        try {
            val locationManager = context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
            val isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
            android.util.Log.i("STATUS", "$isGPSEnabled") // THIS never logs
            onProviderStatusChanged(isGPSEnabled)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
        }
    }
}
```

and my composable

```
@Composable
private fun RequestEnableLocationDialog(
    context: Context,
    onRequestPermissionResult: (Boolean) -> Unit) {

    val locationProviderChangedReceiver = LocationBroadCast(onRequestPermissionResult)

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
        .registerReceiver(locationProviderChangedReceiver, IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION))


    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
                .unregisterReceiver(locationProviderChangedReceiver)
        }
    }


    val openSettingsLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        ) { result ->

            android.util.Log.i("result", "${result} ${result.resultCode}")
            if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Check if location is enabled after user exits Settings
                if (locationEnabled(context)) {
                    // Location is enabled, relaunch LocationPicker
                    onRequestPermissionResult(true)

                }
            }
        }
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = { onRequestPermissionResult(false) },
        title = { Text(text = "Location") },
        text = { Text(text = "Description") },
        confirmButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    openSettingsLauncher.launch(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
                },
            ) {
                Text(text = "Enable Location in Device Settings")
            }
        },
        dismissButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = { onRequestPermissionResult(false) },
            ) {
                Text(text = "Cancel")
            }
        },
    )
}
```

am I doing something wrong?